# How to create Flex Wobble Effect for a component (VBox/HBox etc...)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, effect

Can anyone tell me how can we create a wobbling effect using flex 3?
I need something like the effect which is show in ubuntu when we see an alert or move a folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Mind expanding on that?  What do you mean by 'wobbling'? Have you tried anything before just asking this question? Any code? Where/When is the effect suppose to run?

Comment: @J_A_X I believe he's looking for something similar to the wiggling animation icons get when you tap and hold on them on in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is anything specifically built in Flex to handle the "wobble" effect specifically, but you can combine the Flex Move and bounce effects to create a kind of "wobble":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Bounce id="bounceEasing"/>
    <s:Elastic id="elasticEasing"/>
    <s:Move id="moveRight" 
        target="{myImage}"
        xBy="500"
        duration="2000"
        easer="{elasticEasing}"/>
    <s:Move id="moveLeft" 
        target="{myImage}"
        xBy="-500"
        duration="2000"
        easer="{bounceEasing}"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Image id="myImage" 
    source="@Embed(source='assets/logo.jpg')"/>
<s:Button label="Move Right"
     x="0" y="100" 
    click="moveRight.end();moveRight.play();"/>
<s:Button label="Move Left" 
     x="0" y="125"
    click="moveLeft.end();moveLeft.play();"/>
```

Customize the code above to make smaller movements and link the left and right moves, and you have a wobble.  You might also decide to add an event listener for the MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER to play the wobble effect when the mouse rolls over the component.

Comment: Hi Kyle,first of all thanks for the answer. But i am looking for the wobble effect in flex 3. Can you please help me in getting this effect work in Flex 3?

Comment: Ah my apologies.  Look [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=behaviors_08.html) to find some examples of bounce effects and easing functions for Flex 3.